# How to make the old torch.fft and the new torch.fft.fft compatible in Pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

How can I get a value that represents the same meaning from the new torch.fft.fft, with torch.fft that we could use until v1.7.1?

The documentation is here.

https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.1/generated/torch.fft.html?highlight=torch%20fft

https://pytorch.org/docs/2.0/generated/torch.fft.fft.html?highlight=torch+fft#torch.fft.fft

Specifically, I am having trouble with the following 3D input (assuming a 2D image).

```
    a = torch.tensor([[[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0]],
                      [[2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0], [6.0, 7.0], [8.0, 9.0]],
                      [[3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0], [7.0, 8.0], [9.0,10.0]]])
    # print(torch.fft(a,signal_ndim=2,normalized=False)) #old
```

As the document says, torch.fft.fft accepts the deepest dimension of the input data as [complex], while the old torch.fft seems to accept [real,imag]. (This is the reason why the assumed data and the input dimension are off by one.)

Appendix:

For 2D input (assuming 1D data), the following code succeeded. It may be of help to us.

```
#old @Pytorch v1.7.1
    b = torch.tensor([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
    print(b.shape)
    print(torch.fft(b,signal_ndim=1,normalized=False))
    
#new @Pytorch v1.7.1
import torch.fft
    b = torch.tensor([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0]])
    b = b[:,0]+1j*b[:,1]
    b = torch.unsqueeze(b,1)
    print(b)
    print(b.shape)
    print(torch.fft.fft(b, dim=0))

# With v1.7.1 (example), we can use torch.fft.fft as well, 
# so we do not need to prepare two environments.
# However, we cannot use it at the same time as the old torch.fft 
# because the module names conflict.
```

Output

```
#old
torch.Size([3, 2])
tensor([[ 9.0000, 12.0000],
        [-4.7321, -1.2679],
        [-1.2679, -4.7321]])

#new
tensor([[1.+2.j],
        [3.+4.j],
        [5.+6.j]])
torch.Size([3, 1])
tensor([[ 9.0000+12.0000j],
        [-4.7321-1.2679j],
        [-1.2679-4.7321j]])
```

Will appreciate any help...;; Thanks,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Self resolved.

The functionality of the old torch.fft corresponds to the new **torch.fft.fft, fft2**, or **fftn**.

The important thing is the value of signal_ndim in torch.fft, i.e., how many dimensions of FFT you want to perform.
To prepare, we first converse Real (3, 4, 2) -> Complex (3,4)

```
a = torch.view_as_complex(a)
```

Then,

```
# If signal_ndim=1 (1D FFT)
torch.fft.fft(a)

# If signal_ndim=2 (2D FFT)
torch.fft.fft2(a)

# If signal_ndim=k (k>=3)
torch.fft.fftn(a, dim=k)
```

Answer (score 0):

In old Pytorch versions, for complex numbers the last dimension was used to store real and imaginary part in a normal float tensor.

Since 1.7ish, you can use complex types for tensors and these are used in torch.fft.fft.

You can use `torch.view_as_complex`, for example, for the conversion Real (3, 4, 2) -> Complex (3,4) and  `view_as_real` to back an old-style real tensor of shape (3, 4, 2):

```
F = torch.fft.fftn(torch.view_as_complex(a))
F_asreal = torch.view_as_real(F)
```

This should match an 'old' `torch.fft call`

Comment: In the case of signal_ndim=2, the results did NOT match with the code you gave me, but thank you for the useful function on shaping.